# Adding chromalog to STDOUT and file logging

Tags: python, logging, python-3.4

I am using python's builtin `logging` module

```
# create logger with 'spam_application'
logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application')
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.info('information!2') # this DOES go to both STDOUT and the FILE.  but how to chromalog it???
```

The nice thing about this setup is that the output prints *to the terminal* AND to the file *spam.log*.  Now I want to plug [`chromalog`](http://chromalog.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) into this to get color outputs to the terminal.  Normally I would do this by prefacing the above with

```
chromalog.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s   %(filename)s line %(lineno)d   %(levelname)s:   %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d at %I:%M %p and %S secs')
```

Unfortunately, I think chromalog detects that output is going to a file and turns off color.  It would be ideal if chromalog could turn on color for terminal outputs and turn off color for file outputs.

Is this possible?  How would I do this? P.S.  I am open to an alternative to chromalog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's to do with the default colours for `INFO`. This script:

```
import logging

import chromalog

logger = logging.getLogger('foo')

chromalog.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
fh = logging.FileHandler('foo.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.warning('warning!')
```

provides coloured output:

[image]

The log file contains uncolourised output:

```
$ cat foo.log
warning!
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it does seem the default color of the .info() method is not colored for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses [colorlog](https://github.com/borntyping/python-colorlog) instead of chromalog:

```
import logging
import colorlog

FORMAT_TEMPLATE = '%(asctime)s  %(filename)s line %(lineno)d  {}%(levelname)s{}: {}%(message)s'
FORMAT = FORMAT_TEMPLATE.format()
FORMAT_COLOR = FORMAT_TEMPLATE.format('%(log_color)s', '%(reset)s', '%(message_log_color)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(name)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # if you want to see more than just warnings, remember this!!  You can also set this option to a HANDLER if you want that handler to be at a different level.

# create an output to the terminal:
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stdout_handler.setFormatter(
    colorlog.ColoredFormatter(
        FORMAT_COLOR,
        log_colors={
            'DEBUG':    'cyan',
            'INFO':     'green',
            'WARNING':  'yellow',
            'ERROR':    'red',
            'CRITICAL': 'red,bg_white',
        },
    )
)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

# create an output to a file:
fh = logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')
fh.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter(
        FORMAT,
    )
)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# ready to use!:
logger.debug('hi-ho!')
```

Here we create a *Handler* for each output that we want.  This gives more control and the ability to use different formatting options for each output.